# getJSON doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

objecten.js

```
    var data = [ {
            image: 'gallery/objecten/bear.jpg',
            thumb: 'gallery/objecten/bear.jpg',
            title: 'my first image',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum caption',
            link: 'http://example.com'
        }
        ];
```

In my main js file I am doing the following:

```
  $.getJSON("gallery/objecten/objecten.js",function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    alert("hello?");
                });
          });
```

The alert doesn't work, so what's wrong?

Comment: Remove the trailing comma after data

Comment: Your object.js is not valid JSON. Did it pass [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is malformed. Despite of the format, you should not have a `var` declaration. It should be:

objecten.js

```
[{
    "image":"gallery/objecten/bear.jpg",
    "thumb": "gallery/objecten/bear.jpg",
    "title": "my first image",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum caption",
    "link": "http://domain.com"
}]
```

Note that strings and property names in json must be enclosed with `"`

To see more about the json "format" and its encoding rules see http://json.org

Hope this helps. cheers

Answer (score 0):

object.js does not contain json

```
[{
        "image": "gallery/objecten/bear.jpg",
        "thumb": "gallery/objecten/bear.jpg",
        "title": "my first image",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum caption",
        "link": "http://domain.com"
}]
```

Edited - I removed the parentheses that wrapped it, not sure why I put them in I guess I was looking at the example on http://docs.jquery.com/GetJSON which points to a flickr json page that uses parentheses.  Works now.